# How to kill non-existent process?

Tags: port, windows-server-2016, kill-process

I have a  process with PID 4276 which uses port 9191. I need this port to install software. 
can someone tell me how to kill this process? The Windows task manager doesn't show the process and PowerShell is not able to find the task.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check with [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see if you can find more informations about this PID

Comment: @Swisstone The Process Explorer shows nothing with that PID

Comment: More Over after Restarting the Server. The PID Changed. I think that Process starts During startup.

Comment: Sounds suspicious, you may want to investigate the possibility that the server has been compromised by some kind of rootkit.

Comment: I solve my Issue. It is not the answer to the question but it solved my issue.
I disabled all 3rd party services on the server and then restarted the server.